# How to list custom taxonomies in the back end

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I used this code to create a custom post type and custom taxonomies:

```
function register_menus_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'menus', array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Menus',
        'singular_name' => 'Menu',
      ),
      'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'genesis-seo', // Adds SEO Settings for Genesis Framework
        'genesis-layouts', // Adds Layout Settings for Genesis Framework
        'genesis-cpt-archives-settings', // Adds Taxonomies for Genesis Framework
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'exclude_from_search' => false,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'menu' ),
      'query_var' => true,
      'menu_position' => 6,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-clipboard',
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' )
    )
  );
}
//* Add menus Post Type
add_action( 'init', 'register_menus_post_type' );

function rsi_menu_role_type_taxonomy() {
  register_taxonomy( 'menu_role', array( 'menus' ), array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Menu Type', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Category Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Category Types' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Category Types' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category Type' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category Type:' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Category Type' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category Type' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Type' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Menu Categories' ),
      ),
      'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'role-type'
      ),
      'hierarchical' => true,
    )
  );
}
//* Add Role Taxonomy for menus Post Type
add_action( 'init', 'rsi_menu_role_type_taxonomy', 0 );
```

All works fine with the posts and categories except one thing:

When I list all the custom post types in the back end, I wanna be able to see the categories as well.

I had used this code before in the register function:

```
'taxonomies' => array('category')
```

But that it is not write because it shows the categories from the general post types.
How can I adjust my code to be able to view the categories?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you list the custom post types?